# Cannot access internet wlan0 WiFi Adapter

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, hardware

I am trying to connect internet using a USB WiFi Adapter I bought this afternoon. It is a **TP-LINK TL-WN725N**.

1) - I searched on the internet, and many users are using this adapter.
I first installed the needed driver, following this method :

[Usb driver by Raspberry Kernel versions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=462982#p462982)

2) - The thing is that the raspberry detects the USB adapter, because it is listed when executing `ifconfig` command :

```
wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:e3:27:19:f9:05  
      adr inet6: fe80::817:3e4d:1acb:e06e/64 Scope:Lien
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:16 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

3) - When starting `wpa_gui`, no adapter is found, and the GUI displays "`Could not get status from wpa_supplicant`".

I saw that many people had the same issue.
I tried many configurations, with the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces`.

**intefaces :**

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
auto wlan0

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

**wpa_supplicant.conf :**

```
trl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_suppliment GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="ssid"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
        eap=PEAP
        identity="user"
        password="password"
        phase2="auth=MD5"

}
```

Finally, the Wifi adapter works, because the `iwlist wlan0 scan` prints all the WiFi hotspots around me.
I tried everything I saw on the internet, but I can't make that WiFi adapter to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I decided to reinstall Raspbian, with the USB WiFi adapter plugged-in.
Now everything works, I did not have to configure anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

wpa-ssid "ssid"
wpa-psk "password"
```

Comment: `dhcp` not `manual`. You don't have to mess with your wpa_supplicant.conf file. Put it back to default.

Comment: Are you aware what the "default" actually is?

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how to configure the WPA settings through the interface file, because as you can see on the snippet I have posted, the WiFi hotspot i'm dealing with requires complex authentication.

And, at the beginning, my wpa_supplicant.conf file was empty. I added the two lines after reading a tutorial.

Comment: And also, I would like - if possible - to use wpa_gui.